# Put Text on Odd Pages Only

Tags: backgrounds, blank-page

For a project, I am trying to create a document that looks like Martin Luther's *95 Theses*. For this document, I need my paper to look like parchment. I found a suitable image for a background, but need it printed on the backs of pages, not just the front. To do this, I must print the document double-sided, with every even page devoid of text. Each page must still have the background.

How can I only print text on every odd page, but not even ones?

Below is my LaTeX in full.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[latin]{babel}
\usepackage{eso-pic,graphicx}
\usepackage{savetrees}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\rmnum}[1]{\romannumeral #1}
\newcommand{\Rmnum}[1]{\expandafter\@slowromancap\romannumeral #1@}
\makeatother

\title{Disputatio pro Declaratione Virtutis Indulgentiarum}
\author{Dr.~Martin Luther}
\date{Pridie Kalendas Novembris \Rmnum{1517}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\AddToShipoutPictureBG{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{parchemin_6.jpg}}

\begin{enumerate}[i.]
  \item Dominus et magister noster Iesus Christus dicendo `Penitentiam agite.’
    omnem vitam fidelium penitentiam esse voluit.
  \item Quod verbum de penitentia sacramentali (id est confessionis et
    satisfactionis, que sacerdotum ministerio celebratur) non potest intelligi.
  \item Non tamen solam intendit interiorem, immo interior nulla est, nisi
    foris operetur varias carnis mortificationes.
  \item Manet itaque pena, donec manet odium sui (id est penitentia vera
    intus), scilicet usque ad introitum regni celorum.
  \item Papa non vult nec potest ullas penas remittere preter eas, quas
    arbitrio vel suo vel canonum imposuit.
  \item Papa non potest remittere ullam culpam nisi declarando, et approbando
    remissam a deo Aut certe remittendo casus reservatos sibi, quibus
    contemptis culpa prorsus remaneret.
  \item Nulli prorus remittit deus culpam, quin simul eum subiiciat humiliatum
    in omnibus sacerdoti suo vicario.
  \item Canones penitentiales solum viventibus sunt impositi nihilque morituris
    secundum eosdem debet imponi.
  \item Inde bene nobis facit spiritussanctus in papa excipiendo in suis
    decretis semper articulum mortis et necessitatis.
  \item Indocte et male faciunt sacerdotes ii, qui morituris penitentias
    canonicas in purgatorium reservant.
  \item Zizania illa de mutanda pena Canonica in penam purgatorii videntur
    certe dormientibus episcopis seminata.
  \item Olim pene canonice non post, sed ante absolutionem imponebantur
    tanquam tentamenta vere contritionis.
  \item Morituri per mortem omnia solvunt et legibus canonum mortui iam
    sunt, habentes iure earum relaxationem.
  \item Imperfecta sanitas seu charitas morituri necessario secum fert
    magnum timorem, tantoque maiorem, quanto minor fuerit ipsa.
  \item Hic timor et horror satis est se solo (ut alia taceam) facere penam
    purgatorii, cum sit proximus desperationis horrori.
  \item Videntur infernus, purgaturium, celum differre, sicut desperatio,
    prope desperatio, securitas differunt.
  \item Necessarium videtur animabus in purgatorio sicut minni horrorem ita
    augeri charitatem.
  \item Nec probatum videtur ullis aut rationibus aut scripturis, quod sint
    extra statum meriti seu augende charitatis.
  \item Nec hoc probatum esse videtur, quod sint de sua beatitudine certe et
    secure, saltem omnes, licet nos certissimi simus.
  \item Igitur papa per remissionem plenariam omnium penarum non simpliciter
    omnium intelligit, sed a seipso tantummodo impositarum.
  \item Errant itaque indulgentiarum predicatores ii, qui dicunt per pape
    indulgentias hominem ab omni pena solvi et salvari.
  \item Quin nullam remittit animabus in purgatorio, quam in hac vita
    debuissent secundum Canones solvere.
  \item Si remissio ulla omnium omnino penarum potest alicui dari, certum
    est eam non nisi perfectissimis, i.e.  paucissimis, dari.
  \item Falli ob id necesse est maiorem partem populi per indifferentem
    illam et magnificam pene solute promissionem.
  \item Qualem potestatem habet papa in purgatorium generaliter, talem
    habet quilibet Episcopus et Curatus in sua diocesi et parochia specialiter.
  \item Optime facit papa, quod non potestate clavis (quam nullam habet)
    sed per modum suffragii dat animabus remissionem.
  \item Hominem predicant, qui statim ut iactus nummus in cistam tinnierit
    evolare dicunt animam.
  \item Certum est, nummo in cistam tinniente augeri questum et
    avariciam posse: suffragium autem ecclesie est in arbitrio dei solius.
  \item Quis scit, si omnes anime in purgatorio velint redimi, sicut de s.
    Severino et Paschali factum narratur.
  \item Nullus securus est de veritate sue contritionis, multominus de
    consecutione plenarie remissionis.
  \item Quam rarus est vere penitens, tam rarus est vere indulgentias
    redimens, i. e. rarissimus.
  \item Damnabuntur ineternum cum suis magistris, qui per literas veniarum
    securos sese credunt de sua salute.
  \item Cavendi sunt nimis, qui dicunt venias illas Pape donum esse illud
    dei inestimabile, quo reconciliatur homo deo.
  \item Gratie enim ille veniales tantum respiciunt penas satisfactionis
    sacramentalis ab homine constitutas.
  \item Non christiana predicant, qui docent, quod redempturis animas
    vel confessionalia non sit necessaria contritio.
  \item Quilibet christianus vere compunctus habet remissionem
    plenariam a pena et culpa etiam sine literis veniarum sibi debitam.
  \item Quilibet versus christianus, sive vivus sive mortuus, habet
    participationem omnium bonorum Christi et Ecclesie etiam sine literis
    veniarum a deo sibi datam.
  \item Remissio tamen et participatio Pape nullo modo est contemnenda,
    quia (ut dixi) est declaratio remissionis divine.
  \item Difficillimum est etiam doctissimis Theologis simul extollere
    veniarum largitatem et contritionis veritatem coram populo.
  \item Contritionis veritas penas querit et amat, Veniarum autem
    largitas relaxat et odisse facit, saltem occasione.
  \item Caute sunt venie apostolice predicande, ne populus false
    intelligat eas preferri ceteris bonis operibus charitatis.
  \item Docendi sunt christiani, quod Pape mens non est, redemptionem
    veniarum ulla ex parte comparandam esse operibus misericordie.
  \item Docendi sunt christiani, quod dans pauperi aut mutuans egenti
    melius facit quam si venias redimereet.
  \item Quia per opus charitatis crescit charitas et fit homo melior,
    sed per venias non fit melior sed tantummodo a pena liberior.
  \item Docendi sunt christiani, quod, qui videt egenum et neglecto eo
    dat pro veniis, non idulgentias Pape sed indignationem dei sibi vendicat.
  \item Docendi sunt christiani, quod nisi superfluis abundent
    necessaria tenentur domui sue retinere et nequaquam propter venias
    effundere.
  \item Docendi sunt christiani, quod redemptio veniarum est libera,
    non precepta.
  \item Docendi sunt christiani, quod Papa sicut magis eget ita magis
    optat in veniis dandis pro se devotam orationem quam promptam pecuniam.
  \item Docendi sunt christiani, quod venie Pape sunt utiles, si non in
    cas confidant, Sed nocentissime, si timorem dei per eas amittant.
  \item Docendi sunt christiani, quod si Papa nosset exactiones
    venialium predicatorum, mallet Basilicam s. Petri in cineres ire quam
    edificari cute, carne et ossibus ovium suarum.
  \item Docendi sunt christiani, quod Papa sicut debet ita vellet, etiam
    vendita (si opus sit) Basilicam s. Petri, de suis pecuniis dare illis, a
    quorum plurimis quidam concionatores veniarum pecuniam eliciunt.
  \item Vana est fiducia salutis per literas veniarum, etiam si
    Commissarius, immo Papa ipse suam animam pro illis impigneraret.
  \item Hostes Christi et Pape sunt ii, qui propter venias predicandas
    verbum dei in aliis ecclesiis penitus silere iubent.
  \item Iniuria fit verbo dei, dum in eodem sermone equale vel longius
    tempus impenditur veniis quam illi.
  \item Mens Pape necessario est, quod, si venie (quod minimum est) una
    campana, unis pompis et ceremoniis celebrantur, Euangelium (quod maximum
    est) centum campanis, centum pompis, centum ceremoniis predicetur.
  \item Thesauri ecclesie, unde Pape dat indulgentias, neque satis nominati
    sunt neque cogniti apud populum Christi.
  \item Temporales certe non esse patet, quod non tam facile eos
    profundunt, sed tantummodo colligunt multiÂ  concionatorum.
  \item Nec sunt merita Christi et sanctorum, quia hec semper sine Papa
    operantur gratiam hominis interioris et crucem, mortem infernumque
    exterioris.
  \item Thesauros ecclesie s. Laurentius dixit esse pauperes ecclesie, sed
    locutus est usu vocabuli suo tempore.
  \item Sine temeritate dicimus claves ecclesie (merito Christi
    donatas) esse thesaurum istum.
  \item Clarum est enim, quod ad remissionem penarum et casuum sola
    sufficit potestas Pape.
  \item Verus thesaurus ecclesie est sacrosanctum euangelium glorie et
    gratie dei.
  \item Hic autem est merito odiosissimus, quia ex primis facit
    novissimos.
  \item Thesaurus autem indulgentiarum merito est gratissimus, quia ex
    novissimis facit primos.
  \item Igitur thesauri Euangelici rhetia sunt, quibus olim piscabantur
    viros divitiarum.
  \item Thesauri indulgentiarum rhetia sunt, quibus nunc piscantur
    divitias virorum.
  \item Indulgentie, quas concionatores vociferantur maximas gratias,
    intelliguntur vere tales quoad questum promovendum.
  \item Sunt tamen re vera minime ad gratiam dei et crucis pietatem
    comparate.
  \item Tenentur Episcopi et Curati veniarum apostolicarum Commissarios
    cum omni reverentia admittere.
  \item Sed magis tenentur omnibus oculis intendere, omnibus auribus
    advertere, ne pro commissione Pape sua illi somnia predicent.
  \item Contra veniarum apostolicarum veritatem qui loquitur, sit ille
    anathema et maledictus.
  \item Qui vero, contra libidinem ac licentiam verborum Concionatoris
    veniarum curam agit, sit ille benedictus.
  \item Sicut Papa iuste fulminat eos, qui in fraudem negocii veniarum
    quacunque arte machinantur.
  \item Multomagnis fulminare intendit eos, qui per veniarum pretextum
    in fraudem sancte charitatis et veritatis machinantur.
  \item Opinari venias papales tantas esse, ut solvere possint hominem,
    etiam si quis per impossibile dei genitricem violasset, Est insanire.
  \item Dicimus contra, quod venie papales nec minimum venialium peccatorum
    tollere possint quo ad culpam.
  \item Quod dicitur, nec si s. Petrus modo Papa esset maiores gratias
    donare posset, est blasphemia in sanctum Petrum et Papam.
  \item Dicimus contra, quod etiam iste et quilibet papa maiores habet,
    scilicet Euangelium, virtutes, gratias, curationum. ut Co. XII.
  \item Dicere, Crucem armis papalibus insigniter erectam cruci Christi
    equivalere, blasphemia est.
  \item Rationem reddent Episcopi, Curati et Theologi, Qui tales sermones
    in populum licere sinunt.
  \item Facit hec licentiosa veniarum predicatio, ut nec reverentiam Pape
    facile sit etiam doctis viris redimere a calumniis aut certe argutis
    questionibus laicorm.
  \item Scilicet. Cur Papa non evacuat purgatorium propter sanctissimam
    charitatem et summam animarum necessitatem ut causam omnium iustissimam, Si
    infinitas animas redimit propter pecuniam funestissimam ad structuram
    Basilice ut causam levissimam.
  \item Item. Cur permanent exequie et anniversaria defunctorum et non
    reddit aut recipi permittit beneficia pro illis instituta, cum iam sit
    iniuria pro redemptis orare.
  \item Item.  Que illa nova pietas Dei et Pape, quod impio et inimico
    propter pecuniam concedunt animam piam et amicam dei redimere, Et tamen
    propter necessitatem ipsius met pie et dilecte anime non redimunt eam
    gratuita charitate.
  \item Item. Cur Canones penitentiales re ipsa et non usu iam diu in
    semet abrogati et mortui adhuc tamen pecuniis redimuntur per concessionem
    indulgentiarum tanquam vivacissimi.
  \item Item. Cur Papa, cuius opes hodie sunt opulentissimis Crassis
    crassiores, non de suis pecuniis magis quam pauperum fidelium struit unam
    tantummodo Basilicam sancti Petri.
  \item Item. Quid remittit aut participat Papa iis, qui per
    contritionem perfectam ius habent plenarie remissionis et participationis.
  \item Item. Quid adderetur ecclesie boni maioris, Si Papa, sicut
    semel facit, ita centies in die cuilibet fidelium has remissiones et
    participationes tribueret.
  \item Ex quo Papa salutem querit animarum per venias magis quam
    pecunias, Cur suspendit literas et venias iam olim concessas, cum sint eque
    efficaces.
  \item Hec scrupulosissima laicorum argumenta sola potestate
    compescere nec reddita ratione diluere, Est ecclesiam et Papam hostibus
    ridendos exponere et infelices christianos facere.
  \item Si ergo venie secundum spiritum et mentem Pape predicarentur,
    facile illa omnia solverentur, immo non essent.
  \item Valeant itaque omnes illi prophete, qui dicunt populo Christi
    `Pax pax,’ et non est pax.
  \item Bene agant omnes illi prophete, qui dicunt populo Christi `Crux
    crux,’ et non est crux.
  \item Exhortandi sunt Christiani, ut caput suum Christum per penas,
    mortes infernosque sequi studeant.
  \item Ac sic magis per multas tribulationes intrare celum quam per
    securitatem pacis confidant.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you show us a full MWE of your problem?

Comment: Since your document is, in fact, onesided, have you considered adding those even 'blank' pages at the end? I mean having a post-processor which will take the onesided PDF an have them merged several times with a single 'blank' page. This way you would have the option to print either of the versions (onesided or twosided) and you won't have to deal with odd/even page issues while writing the paper.

Comment: is there a reason you can't use the `background` package with `[oneside]`, and then print the output single-sided?

Comment: What about the page numbering? Should even pages still be numbered?

Comment: Perhaps you could make a PDF file consisting of two copies of the background image, and print as many copies of that (two-sided) as the number of sheets you'll need, then re-feed those sheets into the printer to print your actual document, one-sided. Of course this depends on whether your printer can handle printing on top of a previous printout without ruining it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your document is, in fact, onesided, have you considered adding those even 'blank' pages at the end? I mean having a post-processor which will take the onesided PDF an have them merged several times with a single 'blank' page. This way you would have the option to print either of the versions (onesided or twosided) and you won't have to deal with odd/even page issues while writing the paper. This MWE would do it:

```
\documentclass{article}

 \usepackage{pdfpages}
 \usepackage{forloop} 

\begin{document}

\def\numberofpages{4}%I don't know how to get it automatically
\newcounter{ct}
\forloop{ct}{1}{\value{ct} < \numberofpages}{
 \includepdf[pages=\thect]{onesidedwork.pdf}
 \includepdf[pages=\numberofpages]{onesidedwork.pdf}
}

\end{document}
```

In the onesided work you just have to add a blank page at the end which has the same background:

```
  \item Exhortandi sunt Christiani, ut caput suum Christum per penas,
    mortes infernosque sequi studeant.
  \item Ac sic magis per multas tribulationes intrare celum quam per
    securitatem pacis confidant.
\end{enumerate}

\clearpage
\renewcommand\thepage{}
~

\end{document}
```